# Acessing agent's parameter value

Tags: agent

I was trying to access parameter value of an agent. I created an agent as 'Load' which was created based on database value. while mapping the parameter value with database column value, first i didn't take all as it was not needed. Later i added new parameters in the database and added the parameters in the load agent and mapped accordingly. But when i was trying to access the value of those new parameters, i am getting null value

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jb09L.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lw1ic.png)

Can anyone please help